# Python WX - Returning user input from wx Dialog

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, boa-constructor

I'm new to Python and WX. I created a simple test dialog shown below that prompts the user with a combobox. I would like to capture the value from the combox in my main program. How do I call it from my main program?

This is how I was purposing to call it that displays the dialog but does not currently capture the value from the combobox:

```
    import highlight
    highlight.create(self).Show(True)
    a = highlight.OnComboBox1Combobox(self)
    print a
```

The name of the Dialog file is "highlight". Below is the code:

```
#Boa:Dialog:Dialog2

import wx

def create(parent):
    return Dialog2(parent)

[wxID_DIALOG2, wxID_DIALOG2COMBOBOX1, wxID_DIALOG2STATICTEXT1, 
] = [wx.NewId() for _init_ctrls in range(3)]

class Dialog2(wx.Dialog):
    def _init_ctrls(self, prnt):
        # generated method, don't edit
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, id=wxID_DIALOG2, name='', parent=prnt,
              pos=wx.Point(264, 140), size=wx.Size(400, 485),
              style=wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE, title='Dialog2')
        self.SetClientSize(wx.Size(384, 447))

        self.comboBox1 = wx.ComboBox(choices=['test1', 'test2'],
              id=wxID_DIALOG2COMBOBOX1, name='comboBox1', parent=self,
              pos=wx.Point(120, 16), size=wx.Size(130, 21), style=0,
              value=u'wining\n')
        self.comboBox1.SetToolTipString(u'comboBox1')
        self.comboBox1.SetLabel(u'wining\n')
        self.comboBox1.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.OnComboBox1Combobox,
              id=wxID_DIALOG2COMBOBOX1)

        self.staticText1 = wx.StaticText(id=wxID_DIALOG2STATICTEXT1,
              label=u'test', name='staticText1', parent=self, pos=wx.Point(88,
              16), size=wx.Size(19, 13), style=0)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self._init_ctrls(parent)


        ##print get_selection
        ##print get_selection1

    def OnComboBox1Combobox(self, event):
        get_selection = self.comboBox1.GetValue()
        return get_selection
```

Answer (score 11):

There are lots of dialog examples out there. Here are a couple:

- [The Dialogs of wxPython](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/26/the-dialogs-of-wxpython-part-1-of-2/) (Part 1 of 2)
- http://zetcode.com/wxpython/dialogs/

Basically, all you need to do is instantiate your dialog, show it and then before you close it, extract the value. The typical way to do it is something like this:

```
myDlg = MyDialog()
res = myDlg.ShowModal()
if res == wx.ID_OK:
    value = myDlg.myCombobox.GetValue()
myDlg.Destroy()
```

**Update:** Here's a more full-fledged example:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyDialog(wx.Dialog):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None, title="Dialog")

        self.comboBox1 = wx.ComboBox(self, 
                                     choices=['test1', 'test2'],
                                     value="")
        okBtn = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_OK)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.comboBox1, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        sizer.Add(okBtn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

########################################################################
class MainProgram(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Main Program")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Open dialog")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onDialog)

        self.Show()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onDialog(self, event):
        """"""
        dlg = MyDialog()
        res = dlg.ShowModal()
        if res == wx.ID_OK:
            print dlg.comboBox1.GetValue()
        dlg.Destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainProgram()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Mike, Thank you for the reply. When I use res = myDlg.ShowModal() it does not work but if I change it to res <> myDlg.ShowModal() it does work. Do you know why? Thanks.

Comment: It should work. I'd need a runnable example and traceback to know what's going on.

Comment: it would be good to add what code needs to be in the custom dialog as well as the main application. The OPs question is not covered by the zetcode custom dialog example