# wx.python How can I get updated value of a List of the main frame to the second frame?

Tags: python, frame

After I open my application, there would be a button that opens the second frame. so I want to tell my second frame to grab information based on a List that its value would be appended to by main frame.
**For Example**
In the main frame, there is `self.pubID` and after I do an action I append a number to that list. after than I open the second frame but it doesn't grab that value that I appended, means it can't get the updated information from that list. 
Thanks to you for your help. I know the code I gave looks awful but the whole script might be long and confusable to upload so I hope it shows something.

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title)
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

    def OnSelect(self, event):        
        item = event.GetSelection()
        del self.pubID[:]
        self.pubID.append(item)
    def onInsert(self, event):
            self.Lin = InLink("Insert")
            self.Lin.Show()
class InLink(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, pos=(150,150), size=(200,200))    
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
```

Comment: I am a bit confused about what you're trying to do. I understand that `InLink` needs information from `MyFrame`. Will `InLink` return infromation back to `MyFrame`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `InLink` needs to know what's inside `MyFrame.pubID`. Well there's a simple solution to that problem: pass it to your constructor. So your `InLink.__init__()` becomes this:

```
class InLink(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,title, pubID):
        #now you can easily get the value from pubID
        ...
```

However, I think you have some problems in their code beyond just that. I posted a comment asking you to explain in more detail what you wanted to do. From reading your question I *think* you want `InLink` to return some value that that `MyFrame` will use. Is this correct? If so, instead of using a `wx.Frame` you should be using a `wx.Dialog`. Here is [a previous SO post about `wx.Dialog`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10522076/1369712). That answer contains links to other tutorials to help you get started.

Comment: Thanks for both of you. 
I found a solution for what I wanted to do. for second class I passed Parent and then self.parent = parent. and so on.. then I can use any variable of my main frame by calling self.parent.pubID or whatever.

Comment: @jesy2013 Oh, that's not a great idea. It will *work* but it kind of breaks [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29). You **should** specify `MyFrame` as the parent of `InLink` because that way wxPython will link them together, but I think you should pass `pubID` explicitly, like in my answer. Otherwise `InLink` will always depend on a `MyFrame` existing. If `InLink` **cannot** exist with a `MyFrame` then maybe you should look at using a `wx.Dialog`.

Comment: thanks. well actually my InLink frame should depend on MyFrame and if MyFrame not exist then no InLink is necessary. Since I found it I used it a lot and it is very useful and till now I can't see any disadvantage of it. and it is not just about pubID, it is about calling anything from other classes. and if I use something like self.myframe=MyFrame(self) it is bad, do you know why? because it doesn't bring me the updated values from variables or wherever from MyFrame class. what do you think about this updated thing I mentioned?